# Curious Bash pattern substitution behaviour

Tags: bash

This function `f()` should be extremely simple yet it works in baffling ways:

```
f() {
  a=(cyan red green blue orange violet)
  shopt -s extglob
  echo 1: -${a[@]/!($1)}-
  echo 2: -${a[@]/!($1)/}-
  echo 3: -${a[@]/!("$1")/}-
  echo 4: -"${a[@]/!($1)/}"-
  echo 5: -${a[@]/!($1)/x}-
}
echo ORANGE
f orange # ends in e like blue
echo YELLOW
f yellow
```

The output is (please also note the blank/spacing):

```
ORANGE
1: - e -
2: - e -
3: - e -
4: -    e -
5: -x x x x xe x-
YELLOW
1: - -
2: - -
3: - -
4: -     -
5: -x x x x x x-
```

Why the last character of the sought word only?! (in this case `e` of `orange`)

The expect output is `orange` rather than just `e`

Note: I would also expect to see *no* blanks in some places where I see *one* blank there..

Comment: As @ormaaj implied in a comment below, `shopt -s extglob` does not work *inside* a function.  Code that follows `extglob` is compiled differently, and a function only gets compiled (once) when declared.  Doing that `shopt` at runtime is too late.  This is not an answer to your question though, still puzzling over that...

Comment: @cdarke: So why does my code work, but if I remove the `shopt` line, it does not anymore?

Comment: Interesting, which version of Bash are you using?

Comment: Same here: `OS X: 10.8.3; Bash: 4.2.42(2)-release` and `Linux v3.5.0-25-generic Ubuntu 12.10; Bash : 4.2.37(1)-release`

Comment: 4.2.24 here, x86_64-suse-linux-gnu and 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the pattern is not anchored, so for example for `orange`, the longest string that does not match `orange` is `orang`. It is therefore removed and only `e` remains there. As there is no way how to specify anchors in bash, you have to create them yourself:

```
#! /bin/bash
f() {
    a=(cyan red green blue orange violet '1 2')
    a=("${a[@]/#/|}")
    a=("${a[@]/%/|}")
    shopt -s extglob
    echo ["${a[@]/|!($1)|/-}"]
}
echo ORANGE
f orange # ends in e like blue
echo YELLOW
f yellow
```

Comment: No, shell patterns are always implicitly anchored at both ends. Your extglob is also not taking effect. Never set it within a function.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiring insight.. I could not see what you obviously can see. Is there no way to anchor the pattern without essentially altering the accepted values as you do, prepending/appending a delimiter, though?

Comment: @Robottinosino: None I know of. I usually reach for Perl when I need to do more complex string manipulation.

Comment: Shell patterns are not implicitly anchored in parameter expansion: `foo=alligator; echo ${foo/ga}` prints `allitor`.

Comment: @chepner: You can anchor the left or the right end with `/#` and `/%` respectivelly, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @choroba, yes, I was responding to ormaaj's assertion.

Comment: Yes, I knew that... it's unique to the substitution expansion, all other PEs are anchored. It doesn't help that `!()` is documented by one sentence in every manpage ever, and has no regex equivalent that I'm aware of, though I've yet to notice an incompatibility in its behavior in any shell. This works mostly but not quite like `.*(?<!orange)`.